# Find the minimum positive difference between elements in vector

Tags: matlab

```
A = [1 3 5 8]
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I would like to create a vector `C` which returns the *rownumber* of the element in vector `A` with the smallest non-negative difference to each element in vector `B`.

So, given the example above, it should return:

```
C = [1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll get more help if you show what you've tried, and explain where you're getting stuck.  Please check the "help" link at the top of the page for a tour of what the site is about, how to ask questions, etc.

Comment: Are the arrays always sorted like in your example?

Comment: Yes, arrays are always sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
A = [1 3 5 8]
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

%create matrices of the values to subtract
[a,b] = meshgrid(A,B);
%subtract
aLessB = a-b;
%make sure we don't use the negative values
aLessB(aLessB < 0) = Inf;
%sort the subtracted matrix
[dum, idx] = sort(aLessB, 2, 'ascend');
```

idx(:,1) is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
 D = bsxfun(@minus, A', B);
 D(D < 0) = Inf;
 [~, C] = min(D, [], 1);
```